# Access Options Window Link is hidden

Tags: windows, microsoft-access-2007

I created a database and I chose there in the "Access Options" window to hide the navigation menu.

As a result, my access database doesn't show up the "Create" tab anymore, or any other tabs but the "Home" one, like you see in the attached screenshot.

Not only the navigation tabs are gone, but when I click the "Start" button in Access, the only option I have is "Exit Access" and the "Access Options button is gone as well, making switching the navigation options impossible.

The lack of menus is seen here, the start menu is nearly gone due to the speed it dissapears when taking the screenshot, but it's marked by a red arrow:

[image: 1]

Answer (score 1):

To restore the normal toolbars, take the following steps:

- Exit your database.
- Select the database in Windows Explorer, but do not open it.
- Hold down the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to open the database in "bypass" mode (keep holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> until the database is fully loaded).
- You should now see the full menus.

Since you disabled more than just the navigation menu, you will need to go back to **File** => **Options** => **Current Database** and check the **Allow Full Menus** option.

[image]

Comment: Really informative +1.